# Analyzing/FIxing Index on large MySql Table

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have indexes on a Company Table of 63 million records Company, City and State independently but also have a compound index called `Company_NA` which is made up of Company,City,State.

For some reason when I do

```
Select Count(*) from Companies group by COMPANY,CITY,STATE
```

Explain does not choose any Index

If I do

```
Select Count(*) from Companies Force Index (COMPANY_NA) group by COMPANY,CITY,STATE
```

it naturally uses that key but the query takes so long I stopped it after 5 minutes.

Is there a better way to index, to analyze indexes or things to check for to understand why this is so slow (unless this is as good as it gets given the table size)

For what it is worth there are 51 Unique States, 7k Unique Cities. I cannot get a unique count on Companies because when I run

```
Select count(*) from Companies group by Company
```

I had to kill the query after 15 minutes.  I did check Explain on the above query and it used the Company Index as the key:

- Select Type: Simple
- Table: Companies
- Type: Index
- Possible Keys: ''
- Key: Company
- Key Len: 153 (not sure why, the varchar is 50)
- Ref: ''
- Rows: 6235080
- Extra: Using index

---

Update:

I created a duplicate empty table from which I then removed extraneous fields and all the indexes, then adding back three indexes:

- Unique: Company,Address,City,State
- UniqueCity: Company,City,State
- Company: Company

I also ran

```
Alter Table Company Auto_Increment=1
```

Since my Auto-Increment was over 10,000,000 due to ongoing work.

Continuing to test

Comment: here is a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e1645/1 so as you can see mysql use index `COMPANY_NA` by default. so show me your table schema to prove what you described in your post. and it would be perfect if you provide fiddle with several thousands records to play with

Comment: @Alex For now I duplicated the table (empty), removed extraneous fields, reduced type sizes where I could (varchar from 255 to 50 for instance), removed all indexes and made new ones. Inserting from old table to new and will test on that and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch!  Do not reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Do you have both `UNIQUE(Company,Address,City,State)` and `UNIQUE(Company,City,State)`?  There is no need for the first one to be `UNIQUE`.

Do you have `INDEX(Company)`?  That is unnecessary since you have two other indexes with that column.

Are you sure that there cannot be two companies in the same city with the same name?

`Select count(*) from Companies group by Company` is meaningless.  Did you mean to count the number of times each Company shows up: `Select Company, count(*) from Companies group by Company`?  Or did you mean to count the number of rows: `Select count(*) from Companies`?

Regardless of which you meant to run, it will take time to go through 63 million records in the table or in an index.

Is the table InnoDB?

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  It should be set to about 70% of *available* RAM.

If there are 63M rows, but the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value was only around 10M, something is seriously wrong.

Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS` also.